# Modified booth multiplication algorithm

Tags: verilog, cpu-architecture

I use ModelSim to simulate booth multiplication. I have this code but it's true when `b = 5`, and when I give other numbers for `b` the result is like this=65563.
I try both signed and unsigned but the result is false.
I just confused where is problem.

```
module multiply(p,a,b,clock);
output [15:0] p;
input [7:0]  a,b;
input clock;
reg [15:0] p,ans;
integer i;
integer operate;
initial
begin
  p=16'b0;
  ans=16'b0;
end
always @(negedge clock)
begin
  p=16'b0;
  for(i=1;i<=7;i=i+2)
  begin
    if(i==1)
      operate=b[0]-b[1]-b[1];
    else
      operate=b[i-1]-b[i-2]-b[i]-b[i];
      case(operate)
        1:
        begin
          ans=a;
          ans=ans<<(i-1);
          p=p+ans;
        end
        2:
        begin
          ans=a<<1;
          ans=ans<<(i-1);
          p=p+ans;
        end
        -1:
        begin
          ans=~a+1;
          ans=ans<<(i-1);
          p=p+ans;
        end
        -2:
        begin
          ans=a<<1;
          ans=~ans+1;
          ans=ans<<(i-1);
          p=p+ans;
        end
      endcase
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a problem with your method - I ran the following testbench on your code, which cycled thorugh 1-9 for both `a` and `b`. I'd suggest giving it a try:

```
module tb();

  reg clk;
  reg [7:0]a;
  reg [7:0]b;
  wire [15:0] p;
  integer i,j,k;

  multiply inst (p,a,b,clk);

  initial clk = 0;

  always #5 clk=~clk;

  initial
  begin
    a=0;
    b=0;
    for (j=1; j<10; j=j+1)
      for (k=1; k<10; k=k+1)
      begin
        a=j;
        b=k;
        #20 $display("%d * %d = %d", a, b, p);
      end
  end
endmodule
```

The results were as follows:

```
  1 *   1 =     1
  1 *   2 = 65530
  1 *   3 = 65531
  1 *   4 =     4
  1 *   5 =     5
  1 *   6 = 65534
  1 *   7 = 65535
  1 *   8 = 65512
  1 *   9 = 65513
  2 *   1 =     2
  2 *   2 = 65524
  2 *   3 = 65526
  2 *   4 =     8
  2 *   5 =    10
  2 *   6 = 65532
  2 *   7 = 65534
  2 *   8 = 65488
  2 *   9 = 65490
  ...
```

I'm not sure what you intent is in each of the `case` options, but when the `operate=-1` or `-2` branches are used, the values are incorrect. Double-check your logic there.

Additionally, `operate` can never have a value of 2 (one of your `case` options), and could have a value of -3 (ex. `b=10`), which you haven't covered.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Modified and Working code and the testbench to evaluate the module.

```
module MBA_module(p,a,b,clock);
    output [15:0] p;
    input [7:0]  a, b;
    input clock;
    reg [15:0] p,ans;

    integer i, lookup_tbl;
    integer operate;

    initial
    begin
        p=16'b0;
        ans=16'b0;
    end

    always @(negedge clock)
    begin
        p=16'b0;
        for(i=1;i<=7;i=i+2)
        begin
            if(i==1)
                lookup_tbl = 0;
            else
                lookup_tbl = b[i-2];

            lookup_tbl = lookup_tbl + 4*b[i] + 2*b[i-1]; 

            if(lookup_tbl == 0 || lookup_tbl == 7)
                operate = 0;
            else if(lookup_tbl == 3 || lookup_tbl == 4)
                operate = 2;
            else
                operate = 1;
            if(b[i] == 1)
                operate = -1*operate;

            case(operate)
            1:
                begin
                    ans=a;
                    ans=ans<<(i-1);
                    p=p+ans;
                end
            2:
                begin
                    ans=a<<1;
                    ans=ans<<(i-1);
                    p=p+ans;
                end
            -1:
                begin
                    ans=~a+1;
                    ans=ans<<(i-1);
                    p=p+ans;
                end
            -2:
                begin
                    ans=a<<1;
                    ans=~ans+1;
                    ans=ans<<(i-1);
                    p=p+ans;
                end
            endcase
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Below is the testbench

```
module MBA_mod_tb;

    // Inputs
    reg [7:0] a;
    reg [7:0] b;
    reg clock;

    // Outputs
    wire [15:0] p;

    // Variables
    integer j,k;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    MBA_module uut (
        .p(p), 
        .a(a), 
        .b(b), 
        .clock(clock)
    );

    initial clock = 0;
    always #5 clock = ~clock;

    initial
    begin
        a=0;
        b=0;
        for (j=1; j<10; j=j+1)
            for (k=1; k<11; k=k+1)
                begin
                    a=j;
                    b=k;
                    #20 $display("%d * %d = %d", a, b, p);
                end
    end      
endmodule
```